# REST, MVC - In which layer should link creation for Resources happen?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, dto

The following is an abstract case for my scenario.

After a `GET` request over the `/customers/:id` endpoint, the `Request Handler` in the **Controller** calls a function from the **Service** which returns the `Customer` with the specified id. Afterward, in the **Controller**, the `Customer` received is converted to a `CustomerResourceDTO`.

```
    @GetMapping("customers/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<CourseResourceDTO> getSingleCustomer(@PathVariable int id) {
        Customer customer = customerService.getSingleCustomer(id);
        CustomerResourceDTO customerResourceDTO = new CustomerResourceDTO(customer);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(courseResourceDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

And in the `CustomerResourceDTO` constructor, links are also created.

```
@Getter @Setter
public class CustomerResourceDTO extends ResourceSupport {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    public CustomerResourceDTO (Customer customer) {
        this.firstName = customer.firstName;
        this.lastName = customer.lastName;
        add(new Link("https://linkToSelf").withSelfRel());
    }
}
```

Is it a good practice to set links in the DTO/Resource creation, or should I delegate that to another class/layer?

Comment: what is the purpose of the link ?, is it related to the customer like uniquely identifying it ? more information needs to be provided regarding the use case of the link to determine its generation layer.

Comment: The link is the URI where the respective customer is found, like "http://localhost:8080/customer/1". You can find more about the purpose of links in a REST architecture, by looking over HATEOAS.  My main concern is where should I put the logic for link creation, no matter their purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a rich domain model perspective; I added the following **methods** to my DTOs which extend *ResourceSupport*: `addSelfLink` and `addLink`(to add a link to another resource), otherwise, in my opinion, they should find a place in the *Service* and be called in the *Controller*.